# Parallax stars on canvas. Is this too much for a website?

Tags: javascript, html

New to web dev. I wanted to have stars moving across the page. However, I am worried that this might be too much to compute for a simple website ? or perhaps there is a way to optimize the code?

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const starCount = [700, 200, 100]
const stars = []

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false)
resizeCanvas()
function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    drawStars()
}

function drawStars() {
    for (let i = 0, j = starCount.length; i < j; i++) {
        for (let k = 0, l = starCount[i]; k < l; k++) {
            const x = Math.random() * canvas.width
            const y = Math.random() * canvas.height
            context.beginPath()
            stars.push({ posX: x, posY: y, radius: (i + 1) / 2.5, speed: (3 - i) * 0.25 })
            context.arc(x, y, (i + 1) / 2.5, 0, 360)
            context.fillStyle = 'white'
            context.fill()
        }
    }
}
drawStars()

function redraw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    for (let i = 0, j = stars.length; i < j; i++) {
        const speed = stars[i].speed
        context.beginPath()
        if ((stars[i].posY -= speed) < 0) {
            stars[i].posY = canvas.height
        } else {
            stars[i].posY -= speed
        }
        context.arc(stars[i].posX, stars[i].posY, stars[i].radius, 0, 360)
        context.fillStyle = 'white'
        context.fill()
    }
}

setInterval(() => {
    redraw()
}, 17);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things here: You have to know your target audience for a website to know if you're doing too much on the sight. Targeting the wealthy? They probably have disposable income for good computers and can handle the task. Targetting as broad spectrum as possible? Make your site flex depending on the viewer. If you can't sustain a high frame rate, then fall back to a static image.

Next performance: You can get better performance from webgl, but you have to climb the mountain that is webgl.

Other performance: setInterval is bad practice for redraw loops. Use requestAnimationFrame to properly make changes on the main UI loop. If you need to reduce the frame rate, then skip some frames.

Canvas performance: Canvas is state based, things like fillStyle need not be reapplied if your state didn't change before, so take those out of your loop. You can micro-optimize your loop by not using an evaluated property in your conditional:

```
for (let i = 0, endi = stars.length; i < endi; ++i)
```

There's probably more little things you can do...

Next design: If it's truly an element that you believe makes your site stand out, then put in the effort to make the design work for everyone.